# flask-sqlalchemy and pure sql commands

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm new to sqlalchemy, I have a flask app and I want to use flask-sqlalchemy with sqlite for flask-admin in it. I wanted to know if I could use pure sql commands while I'm using sqlalchemy or not.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, for example:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = Session()

sql = text('SELECT id FROM users')
result = session.execute(sql)
ids = [row[0] for row in result]
print(ids)
```